# How to index an N dimensional array using an N-1 dimensional array of indices

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a 4-dimensional array `rand` that I would like to index along the 3rd dimension using a 3-dimensional array `idx`. In the example below, the output should be of shape `[32,100,3]`

```
import numpy as np

# values to be indexed
array = np.random.rand(32, 100, 4, 3)

# values to be indexed along the 3rd dimension of array
idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(32,100,1))

indexed_array = array[idx] # Output here should be [32, 100, 3]
```

What am I doing wrong? A solution would be to loop over every dimension but is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [61]: array = np.random.rand(32, 100, 4, 3)
    ...: 
    ...: # values to be indexed along the 3rd dimension of array
    ...: idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(32, 100, 1))
In [62]: array.shape
Out[62]: (32, 100, 4, 3)
In [63]: idx.shape
Out[63]: (32, 100, 1)
```

With:

```
In [64]: array[idx].shape
Out[64]: (32, 100, 1, 100, 4, 3)
```

we are applying the array `idx` to the first dimension of `array`.

`idx` is indices for the 3rd dimension, not the first.  To apply it we need to specify compatible arrays for the first 2 dimensions (in the `broadcasting` sense):

```
In [66]: array[np.arange(32)[:, None,None], np.arange(100)[:,None], idx].shape
Out[66]: (32, 100, 1, 3)
In [67]: 
In [67]: array[np.arange(32)[:, None], np.arange(100), idx[:,:,0]].shape
Out[67]: (32, 100, 3)
```

There is a newish function that may streamline this (for some people):

```
In [70]: np.take_along_axis(array, idx[:, :, :, None], axis=2).shape
Out[70]: (32, 100, 1, 3)
```

When indexing an array, there's an important distinction between a tuple and an array (or list).

```
arr[1,2,3]  # index each of the 3 dimensions
arr[(1,2,3)]  # equivalent
arr[[1,2,3]]   # index just the first dimension with a list
```

Comment: thank you! the broadcasting method is certainly a lot more intuitive!